# Can I get data from a new object before it is returned?

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet of code, `hour: +date.getHours()` will throw the error `ReferenceError: date is not defined`.

```
    data = d.Data.slice(0, ncandles).map(function(d) {
        return {
            date: new Date(d.time * 1000),
            hour: date.getHours(), //date is not defined
            open: +d.open,
            high: +d.high,
            low: +d.low,
            close: +d.close,
            volume: +d.volume
        };
    }).sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b)); });
```

So far the only way I have been able to get the hour is by creating a new object with the line `hour: new Date(d.time * 1000).getHours()` as seen below. It seems redundant and inefficient to create a new object when one has already been created. How can I handle data from `date` within this scope?

```
data = d.Data.slice(0, ncandles).map(function(d) {
    return {
        date: new Date(d.time * 1000),
        hour: new Date(d.time * 1000).getHours(),
        open: +d.open,
        high: +d.high,
        low: +d.low,
        close: +d.close,
        volume: +d.volume
    };
}).sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b)); });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = d.Data.slice(0, ncandles).map(function(d) {
    let date = new Date(d.time * 1000)
    return {
        date: date,
        hour: date.getHours(),
        open: +d.open,
        high: +d.high,
        low: +d.low,
        close: +d.close,
        volume: +d.volume
    };
}).sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b)); });
```

another way

```
data = d.Data.slice(0, ncandles)
  .map(function(d) {
    let obj = {
      date: new Date(d.time * 1000),
      open: +d.open,
      high: +d.high,
      low: +d.low,
      close: +d.close,
      volume: +d.volume,
    }
    obj.hour = obj.date.getHours()
    return obj
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b))
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. So the object must be created outside of the `return` block before it can be used within the scope of the block?

Comment: "the return block" is actually an object; so u can create an object, add attributes to it and then return it; but you can't use its attributes while creating it.